# Using summarize_at to divide multiple columns by other column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to divide multiple columns by another specified column. The only relevant part of the code is posted below.

```
summarize_at(vars(starts_with('total')),list(~./count_short))
```

The error: 'total_age' must be length 1, not length of set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `summarise/summarise_at` returns a length of 1, but insstead when we divide by the whole column, it is of length n().  So, instead of `summarise_at`, use `mutate_at` to modify the column

```
...
 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('total')),list(~./count_short))
```

or if the need is to. create new column, after the `list` wrap specify a name that will get suffixed with the existing column to create new column

```
... %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('total')),list(value = ~./count_short))
```